# OKHTTP Unexpected Status Line on 3G

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm working on an app and I have a problem with making a POST request with okhttp.

Stack trace (okhttp):

```
12-29 09:29:55.829: W/System.err(1797): java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: HTTP/1.1 
12-29 09:29:55.829: W/System.err(1797):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:58)
12-29 09:29:55.837: W/System.err(1797):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:189)
12-29 09:29:55.837: W/System.err(1797):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
12-29 09:29:55.845: W/System.err(1797):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:676)
12-29 09:29:55.845: W/System.err(1797):     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:205)
12-29 09:29:55.845: W/System.err(1797):     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
12-29 09:29:55.852: W/System.err(1797):     at net.claxi.driver.misc.TaskFragment$LoginTask.doInBackground(TaskFragment.java:156)
12-29 09:29:55.852: W/System.err(1797):     at net.claxi.driver.misc.TaskFragment$LoginTask.doInBackground(TaskFragment.java:1)
12-29 09:29:55.852: W/System.err(1797):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-29 09:29:55.852: W/System.err(1797):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-29 09:29:55.852: W/System.err(1797):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-29 09:29:55.860: W/System.err(1797):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-29 09:29:55.860: W/System.err(1797):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-29 09:29:55.860: W/System.err(1797):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This only happens on 3G on a specific tablet, on Wi-Fi it works fine on the same device. On other devices it works fine both on 3G and Wi-Fi.

For the login request I was using okhttp to make the request. For other requests I was using Retrofit. When I switched to using Rertofit for the login request a weird thing happens. Sometimes it works and sometimes it crashes.

Stack trace when using Retrofit:

```
12-29 09:42:51.337: D/Retrofit(2766): ---- ERROR http://MYSERVER.com:2258/api/loginTaxi
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766): java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: HTTP/1.1 
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:59)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:187)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:78)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:665)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:429)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:374)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:469)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-29 09:42:51.352: D/Retrofit(2766): ---- END ERROR
```

I'm using okhttp-2.1.0, okhttp-urlconnection-2.1.0 and okio-1.1.0.

And when removing okhttp (using Retrofit with default http client)

```
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid status code: -1
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at retrofit.client.Response.<init>(Response.java:42)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:94)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-29 10:24:19.837: D/Retrofit(4727): ---- END ERROR
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default APN contained a proxy that was messing with our requests/responses.

Removing the proxy from the APN resolves the issues.